# How I can prevent LogCat receive everything that makes my mobile?

Tags: java, android, android-logcat

It really bothers me that every time I connect the phone to the PC, the LogCat begins to receive information that does not desire. The idea is to just get the LogCat of the application I'm developing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a filter. You simply open up LogCat and click on the green `+` you'll see in the tools bar. Define the parameters you want to filter and a new filter will open up with just the lines you want.

The most logical way to filter is by your package name, this way your app or apps within a workspace will be logged and the rest stripped.

[image: LogCat filter]